# How to run python from C# without .exe file

Tags: python, c#, command-line, exe

I am a Python beginner and wrote some Python code that I want to run from my C# code.

In all the answers I have seen already, the way was to make a .exe file from the .py one and run it by system call.

However, I want it so that I do not need to make the .exe file and can write the commands with arguments as I could in the command line.

```
 C:\Users\ntuser>   python C:\Users\ntuser\Documents\run_python.py 3
```

Is there a way to do it?
I found a way to pass just one command—but I need to make two: 1. Go to "C:\Users\ntuser" 2. Run the Python code.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you ensure that your user has a Python interpreter installed (and in the `PATH`)? If you can be sure of that, then you can just use the `System.Process` class

Comment: I'm sure that he have it. but I saw that in `System.Process` class I can pass just one command.

Comment: changing the (working) directory does not require you to use `Process` - you can just use [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. (Unless you mean something else by *"go to"*, in which case you need to clarify)

Comment: [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) could be a solution too.

Comment: @dymanoid I know - but I don't want to add it to all the machines that I use

Comment: You don't need to install it separately, you just deploy it as a part of your app. Anyway, it *could* be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found a solution.
Thanks to UnholySheep for the help.

What you need to do is:

1. Make the python as [system variable](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)
2. Go by code to your home directory:

   `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile));`
3. Add this code for calling the python code:

`System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;//if you want to hide the window
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C python pytonPath\\python_code.py";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();//if you want to wait`